# Angular 2 Kendo ui grid Date format not working

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui

Recently I started working on integrating angular 2 and kendo ui grid in my application. Everything works fine except date format. Below is my code.

Please help me

```
<kendo-grid-column field="lastLoginTime" title="LastLoginTime" type="date" format={0:dd/MM/yyyy} width="40">
            </kendo-grid-column>
             <kendo-grid-column field="creationTime" title="CreationTime" type="date" format={0:dd/MM/yyyy} width="40" >           
            </kendo-grid-column>
```

date format is not working.

Thanks & Regards
Ramana.

Comment: Please find below code<kendo-grid-column field="lastLoginTime" title="LastLoginTime" type="date" format={0:dd/MM/yyyy} width="40">
            </kendo-grid-column>
             <kendo-grid-column field="creationTime" title="CreationTime" type="date" format={0:dd/MM/yyyy} width="40" >            
            </kendo-grid-column>

Comment: I have also not been able to get the format property to work. I had to use a cell template.     <kendo-grid-column field="DateColumn" title="Date Column" width="100">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ dataItem.DateColumn | date:"MM/dd/yyyy" }}
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

Answer (score 1):

import  INtlModule

```
import {IntlModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl'
```

bindings

```
[format]="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
```

or

```
{{PaymentDetails.CheckInDate | kendoDate:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Should be in single quote inside double quote

Comment: Thanks that's work for me `{{dataItem.CheckInDate | kendoDate:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `[format]="'{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'"`

That works for me with Grid v 1.1.2

Comment: Like that, but without single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use ng-template in the  element:

```
  <kendo-grid-column field="OrderDate" title="Date">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-orderItem>
      {{ orderItem.OrderDate | date: 'dd.MM.yy' }}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```